# pg_receivewal to cifs network share

Tags: postgresql, barman

I'm trying to setup a pgbarman server to backup a postgresql cluster. The streaming replication is not working when configured to store data on a directory located on a cifs network share. The root problem seem to be related with the pg_receivewal command. I extracted the command barman is executing:

```
$ LANG=C /usr/bin/pg_receivewal --dbname="dbname=replication host=sqlserver.domain.tld port=5432 replication=true user=barman_replication application_name=barman_receive_wal" --verbose --no-loop --no-password --directory=/var/local/backups/Postgresql/Barman/sqlserver-main/streaming --slot=barman_backup --synchronous
pg_receivewal: starting log streaming at 18/DF000000 (timeline 1)
pg_receivewal: could not fsync file "/var/local/backups/Postgresql/Barman/sqlserver-main/streaming": Invalid argument
pg_receivewal: could not open existing write-ahead log file "0000000100000018000000DF.partial": Invalid argument
pg_receivewal: could not fsync file "/var/local/backups/Postgresql/Barman/sqlserver-main/streaming": Invalid argument
pg_receivewal: could not finish writing WAL files: Invalid argument
pg_receivewal: disconnected
```

The user running barman have permissions to read/write on that directory. I don't think this is a permission issue. If I edit the command and replace the --directory argument with a local directory (/tmp/test), the error disappear...

Google didn't helped me so much about that. Any idea what's wrong?

```
$ pg_receivewal --version
pg_receivewal (PostgreSQL) 10.1
```

Comment: Looks like cifs does not support `fsync`.

Comment: There is no workaround for this? I suppose I would have to setup a NFS share...

Comment: I guess so. Can't think of a workaround.